# Manipulation event routing

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I need some guidance with the following. Manipulation events are supposed to route up the visual tree until handled?

I have the following:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Width = 1920;
canvas.Height = 1200;
canvas.IsManipulationEnabled = true;
canvas.AddHandler(ManipulationStartingEvent, new EventHandler<ManipulationStartingEventArgs>(CanvasManipulationStarting), true); 

ScatterViewItem svi = new ScatterViewItem();
svi.AddHandler(ManipulationStartingEvent, new EventHandler<ManipulationStartingEventArgs>(SVIManipulationStarting), true);
svi.Content = canvas;

public void SVIManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
   //e.Handled = true; //This fires if uncommented
}

public void CanvasManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
     e.Handled = true; //This never fires regardless :( sob
}
```

If I click on the canvas, the SVIManipulationStarting fires but if it's uncommented, the CanVasManipulationStarting never fires?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that, if I understand right, the `Canvas` do not raise the manipulation event if you click on it, and that the `ScatterViewItem` (which is the container of the `Canvas`) raised this event, especially if you handle it in the `Canvas` manipulation event handler.

- Are you sure you're clicking on the canvas ? Add a background color to check it. If your `Canvas` do not have a `Background` color, it will not be clickable until you set `IsHitTestVisible` to `true`
- Try to manipulate your `Canvas` without adding it to your `ScatterViewItem` (but to an other existing container). Just to check your `Canvas` behaviour in an other situation.